# Error related to sql mode=only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql

Tags: mysql

i have upgraded my system and have installed MySql 5.7.9 with php for a web application I am working on. I have a query that is dynamically created, and when run in older versions of MySql it works fine. Since upgrading to 5.7 I get this error:
So this is the code that is giving me errors:

```
select *,SUM(payment) as payment,DATE_FORMAT(payment_date,'%b') as month 
from payment 
natural join branch
where YEAR(payment_date)='$year' and MONTH(payment_date)='$month' 
group by branch_id,MONTH(payment_date) 
order by  MONTH(payment_date)
```

I did some googling on the issue, but I don't understand only_full_group_by enough to figure out what I need to do to fix the query. Can I just turn off the only_full_group_by option, or is there something else I need to do?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Replace the select * with select branch_id, month? As an aside Natural joins imply the reader has knowledge of your table schemas a better join for readability would be an inner join or left join

Answer (score 0):

you need to put all columns of selection list in group by

```
select branch_id,MONTH(payment_date),SUM(payment) as payment,DATE_FORMAT(payment_date,'%b') as month 
from payment 
natural join branch
where YEAR(payment_date)='$year' and MONTH(payment_date)='$month' 
group by branch_id,MONTH(payment_date),DATE_FORMAT(payment_date,'%b')
order by  MONTH(payment_date)
```